# Beginner C++ codewars question about rounding (Area of a square)

Tags: c++, return, double, rounding, return-value

Having a problem rounding a value that I have to return to 2 decimal places.
The question is:  Calculate the area of the red square when the length of the circular arc (A) is given as the input. Return the result rounded to two decimals. [IMAGE OF SQUARE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwQ0V.png)
This is what I have written is below. I have tried using std::precision(), but I don't know how to return the value. This is the output I'm getting when I test the code:[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4X7OV.png)

```
#include <math.h> 
#include <iostream>
double square_area(double A) {
  // to do
  // area of sqr = B*H
  // circumfrence of circle = 2*pi*r
  // A = (2*pi*r) / 4
  // r = (A*4)/(2*pi)
  // r= (2*A)/pi
  double r = ((2*A) / M_PI);
  double B = (r*r);
return B;

};
```

Comment: refer to this Article -> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/rounding-floating-point-number-two-decimal-places-c-c/

Answer (score 0):

Your result has a precision of 5, but the online judge just needs a precision of 2.

One way to make it has a precision of 2 is to use the `std::setprecision()` function in the `<iomanip>` header.

```cpp
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    // code
    double result {square_area(double anyNumber)};
    
    use std::fixed to tell the compiler always print a precision of 2
    std::cout << std::fixed <<  std::setprecision(2) << result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I ended up using this solution because I could not figure out how to return the value with your method.                                                           
`#include <cmath>
double square_area(double A)
{
  // area of sqr = B*H
  // circumfrence of circle = 2*pi*r
  // A = (2*pi*r) / 4
  // r = (A*4)/(2*pi)
  // r= (2*A)/pi
 double r = A * 2 / M_PI;
 return std::round(r * r * 100) / 100;

};` sorry the code is formatted like s***, still trying to understand how this site works.

Answer (score 0):

You did great. You tried many things. you just missed one line:

```
#include <cmath> 
#include <iostream>
double square_area(double A) {
    double r = ((2*A) / M_PI);
    double B = (r*r);
    // just add this line. this will round the value.
    B = round(B * 100) / 100;
    // and return it
    return B;
};
```